# Plotting Slopes of interaction effect from Fixed effects model with marginaleffects package (R)

Tags: r, r-marginaleffects

I am running a regression with multiple interaction terms and multiple fixed effects. I am looking to plot the slope (derivative) of a variable, conditional upon it being interacted or not. I came across the `marginaleffects` package, which seems to be able to do this. However, it did not accept the felm model I was using from the `lfe` package, so I switched to using `feols` from the `fixest` package instead. My regression looks like the following:

```
reg <- feols(data = df, outcome ~ interact_dummy * (IV_Dummy1 + control1 + control2) + interact_dummy * (IV_Dummy2 + control1 + control2)| country_fe + year_fe)
```

I then plot attempt to plot the slope using the following

```
plot_slopes(reg, variables = "IV_Dummy1", condition = "interact_dummy")
```

But the plot is the following:
[image]

I would like instead to plot these points connected, showing the increase in the slope caused by the interaction effect. Ideally, this could also have shaded regions for the confidence interval (as the current plot has bounds). Is this issue specific to using a fixed effects model, or the `fixest` package? Is there an alternative package to use, or have I specified the `plot_slopes()` incorrectly

Additionally, the estimates from the `feols` regression are the same as when I ran the regression in the `felm` model, however their significance levels are slightly different. What accounts for this?

EDIT:

(Sample code)

```
reg2 <- feols(data = mtcars, mpg ~ vs * (am + hp + carb) + vs * (disp + hp + carb) | gear + carb)
plot_slopes(reg2, variables = "am", condition = "vs")
```

Comment: For information, `marginaleffects`'s developer decided to not support `lfe` (not saying at all that it's wrong or not, just that it's not an omission): https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/marginaleffects/issues/98

Comment: Can you include a small reproducible example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference in significance between `lfe` and `fixest` is probably due to the fact that `fixest` reports robust standard errors by default. See this vignette: https://lrberge.github.io/fixest/articles/standard_errors.html

The reason why the plot is point-range by default, instead of a continuous line is that the moderating variable is binary, and because it rarely makes sense to plot continuous lines between binary categories (it implies that we can interpolate).

If that is still what you want to do, it is trivial to set the `draw` argument to `FALSE`, extract the raw data, and plot it with `ggplot2`. For example:

```r
library(fixest)
library(marginaleffects)
library(ggplot2)

mod <- feols(hp ~ vs * am | carb, data = mtcars)

# extract raw data for plotting
dat <- plot_slopes(mod, variables = "vs", condition = "am", draw = FALSE)

# convert categorical (binary/factor) variable to numeric
dat$am <- as.numeric(as.character(dat$am))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = am, y = estimate, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_ribbon(alpha = .2) +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(y = "Slopes")
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, this works perfectly! And you've made a spectacular package, I might add.